# Will double strike trigger cipher twice?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say I am playing with a creature that has double strike (e.g. [Two-Headed Cerberus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Two-Headed%20Cerberus)), and I cipher [Hidden Strings](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hidden%20Strings) to it. This allows me to tap/untap up to 2 target permanents whenever the creature deals combat damage to a player.

If my creature then attacked a player and wasn't blocked, and he took the double strike damage, would I then be able to tap/untap 2 target permanents twice? In effect tap/untap 4 target permanents?

I am asking this because my friends and I play with a few different ciphers and have had arguments about this a few times.

Answer (score 7):

Cipher triggers whenever the encoded creature deals combat damage to a player. An unblocked creature with double strike will deal combat damage to the player twice; once in the "first strike" combat damage step, and again in the regular combat damage step. As a result, if an encoded creature with double strike is not blocked, you **will** be able to cast the encoded card twice.

Comment: Yucks, double-strike is so overpowered.