# Does Double Strike mean you count as Attacking twice?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does [Narset, Enlightened Master](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Narset%2C%20Enlightened%20Master)'s ability trigger twice if she has double strike, since she has an ability that says "When (she) attacks"?

Comment: All double strike means is the creature deals both first strike and normal combat damage. They only "attack" once, but they "deal damage" twice.

Answer (score 18):

No.

The trigger, "Whenever ~ attacks" means "Whenever ~ is declared as an attacking creature". A creature with double strike will deal damage in the two combat damage steps, but will only be declared as an attacker once per turn. (Normally, unless some other effect is creating additional combat phases.)

Answer (score 6):

No. Declaring a creature to attack only happens once per combat phase, no matter how often it deals combat damage.

There are [some cards](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+[additional]+[combat]) that grant you additional combat phases.

A creature with Double Strike would only trigger "on dealing (combat) damage" triggers twice.

Answer (score -4):

If, however, Narset also is enchanted by Curiosity (as well as DS), she will count as *dealing combat damage to a player* twice, so you would draw two cards.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. While this may be relevant to the broader issue, this doesn't answer the question of whether double strike counts as attacking twice for the purpose of attack triggers. You may have mistaken this place for behaving like a forum and accepting general discussion on a matter - it doesn't. We're a Q&A site, and answers are expected to directly answer the question. Please see our [tour] to check out how this site works.

Comment: As an extra note to doppelgreener's comment, your answer would have made a good comment for additional information if it had been made in response to the top answer.

Answer (score -6):

Actually, it does count as attacking twice. According to the mtg wiki and some other referances, there is a first-strike attack phase and a regular attack phase. Take a look [Here at the wiki](http://mtg.wikia.com/wiki/Double_Strike). So, due to the fact that she is attacking twice, that power would be activated twice when you declare that she is attacking. If you do not believe me, take a look at some of these other questions where people have asked similar things:

[Double Strike Creatures and Abilities](http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/magic-fundamentals/magic-rulings/magic-rulings-archives/273880-double-strike)
[Triggering abilities Twice With Double Strike](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/20366/will-double-strike-trigger-cipher-twice)

Hope I helped,

-Nick

Comment: Unfortunately this is not correct.  "Attacking" and "dealing combat damage" are two different concepts.  There are two combat damage steps and a creature with double-strike will deal damage in both of them, but there is only one declare attackers step and that is when any "when ~ attacks" abilities will trigger.  The threads you linked to refer to creatures with abilities like "when ~ deals combat damage".

Comment: No problem! It's an easy mistake to make.

Comment: This answer should not be deleted. It's wrong, but it highlights an easy mistake to make. From [the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/254466), "Answers that are wrong or that dispense poor advice should be downvoted, not deleted."